# Embed YouTube videos using ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube

I am using `ng-repeat` directive in Angular to embed some videos fetched from server.

I get video IDs from server and I have following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="media in product.media">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe width="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{{ media.src }}" frameborder="0 " allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I see the output, the video is not showing up. And when I inspect element in Google chrome,
the html doesnt seem to change:

[image: embed youtube video using angular ng-repeat]

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you post a fiddle? It seems to be a wrong src attribute... I should see the value of media.src not the "media.src" string in html

Comment: @faby http://jsfiddle.net/e7LWu/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since 1.2 you can only bind one expression to *[src], *[ng-src] or action. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#you-can-only-bind-one-expression-to-src-ng-src-or-action-).

Use `ng-src` and change your HTML to:

```
ng-src="{{getIframeSrc(media.src)}}"
```

In the controller add:

```
$scope.getIframeSrc = function(src) {
  return 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + src;
};
```

Note that you need to specify the protocol.

You also need to add the URL as trusted by configuring the `$sceDelegate` service:

```
app.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',
    'https://www.youtube.com/**'
  ]);
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/4U5HxNnVDwlF5udRiQa1?p=preview