# How can I get angularJS dynamic content to display in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am generating some tabular content using `ng-repeat` in AngularJS, and I would like to have this content display in an iframe, so that the user can drag it and resize it.

I can't use the iframe `src` attribute, because that requires a URL and I am generating the content on the client.

I probably want some variant of `srcdoc`, but that seems to want a single quoted line of html code.

How can I construct my iframe such that the `ng-repeat` generated content is displayed within?

Comment: unless you can pass your content to a separate angular app on a different page catered to the iframe, this won't work.  there is no way to perform two way binding across an iframe.

Comment: have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757015/embed-youtube-videos-using-ng-repeat-in-angular)?

Comment: You might find this question on [how to make a div resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391440/make-div-resizeable) useful.

Comment: [jQueryUI Draggable Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: Here's [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UBWJLWCYQuP5eCJhZ81k?p=preview) of `ng-repeat` with `iframes`

Comment: @sfletche your examples both load from a url.

Comment: @BSMP Interesting widget, now to get it to be resizable

Answer (score 1):

You can add an AngularJS table to an iframe. The support is limited to HTML5 but it looks something like this:

HTML

```
<iframe id="frame" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" srcdoc="" seamless="true"></iframe>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document.getElementById("mydiv")
```

The `srcdoc` property can be used instead of `src` to indicate you will be providing code for the contents. Seamless is also expected when you use `srcdoc`; it tells the browser that the iframe's contents are supposed to be treated as a part of the website, rather than a nested one. Unfortunately, this will trigger styling changes that eliminate the whole reason you wanted the iframe in the first place (the resize handles disappear). Furthermore, you'd have to inject css files and javascript files into the iframe - it's not worth it.

I'd recommend using something like jQuery UI resizable: https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Here's a fiddle I was using to test out controlling iframe contents. It's very basic but accurately demonstrates how much trouble they actually are: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6a4gavzc/)

Comment: but this does not accept an angular repeat. Thanks for resizable. Will try to combine that with draggable and see what pops out

Comment: jquery or the iframe?

Comment: I am generating the content using AngularJS, not jQuery

Comment: sure, but you can use jQuery in an Angular project

Comment: I know that, I am using jQuery in other places. My point is that this particular content is being generated from Angular, not jQuery, so I would like to stuff the angular generated content into the iframe