# How to embed videos in a div using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm a beginner to angularjs.I'm trying to embed the videos in a div.How can I achieve this ?

Can anyone plese help me out regarding this issue ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed YouTube videos using ng-repeat in Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757015/embed-youtube-videos-using-ng-repeat-in-angular)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video is not working with AngularJS ng-src tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728424/html5-video-is-not-working-with-angularjs-ng-src-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<video controls ng-src="{{videoUrl}}"></video>`

And define `videoUrl` in your controller.